# Invalid syntax when defining python function

Tags: python, function, matrix

I'm trying to define a function that will calculate the minimum amount of steps (and type of steps) to be taken to turn a string into another string. I have the below:

```
def cost(matrix[i][j]):

    a = matrix[i-1][j][0]+1

    b = matrix[i][j-1][0]+1

    if a[i] = b[i]:
        c = matrix[i-1][j-1][0]
    else:
        c = matrix[i-1][j-1][0] +1

    cost0 = min(a, b, c)
    if cost0 = a:
        cost1 = Operation.DELETED
    elif cost0 = b:
        cost1 = Operation.INSERTED
    else:
        cost1 = Operation.SUBSTITUTED

    return (cost0, cost1)
```

as part of my program, where a, b, and c are ints, but when I run it, it throws an invalid syntax error like the following:

```
line 23
    def cost(matrix[i][j]):
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

what could it be?

Comment: Just `def cost(matrix):`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you define a function, you don't specify the dimensions of the array, omit them. Because variables are passed by reference, the array dimensions will be passed automatically

```
def cost(matrix):

    a = matrix[i-1][j][0]+1

    b = matrix[i][j-1][0]+1

    if a[i] = b[i]:
        c = matrix[i-1][j-1][0]
    else:
        c = matrix[i-1][j-1][0] +1

    cost0 = min(a, b, c)
    if cost0 = a:
        cost1 = Operation.DELETED
    elif cost0 = b:
        cost1 = Operation.INSERTED
    else:
        cost1 = Operation.SUBSTITUTED

    return (cost0, cost1)
```